# how to pass value from parent functional component to child class component in react

Tags: reactjs

Hi all I have following code:

Parent functional component

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    function Parent() {
      const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});
      async function fetchData() {
        const res = await fetch("some API data");
        res.json().then((res) => setApiData(res));
       }
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, []);

      return (<div><Child title={apiData.title} /></div>);
    }
    export default Parent;
```

And have following code for my Child class component:

```
    import React from "react";
       class Child extends React.Component {
         render() {
          return (<div> "here should be title from API" </div> )
        }
       }
```

I can successfully fetch my API data, but I have some difficulties to pass to my Child component. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The most common way of passing values is using `props`, and it really doesn't matter if you are using functional or class based components. The gist is still the same, the only difference is that in functional components you should receive props as a normal argument. `const C = props => <div>{props.foo}</div>` and in class based components `props` is a variable scoped in the component's instance so must be acessed via `this`like `this.props.foo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same, as you use it in the functional component (+ adding "this." before the props).

```
import React from "react";
   class Child extends React.Component {
     render() {
      return (<div>{this.props.title}</div> )
    }
   }
```

See more examples here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html